# How do I activate JButton ActionListener inside code (unit testing purposes)?

Tags: java, unit-testing, swing, junit

I need to activate a JButton ActionListener within a JDialog so I can do some unit testing  using JUnit.

Basically I have this:

```
    public class MyDialog extends JDialog {
    public static int APPLY_OPTION= 1;
    protected int buttonpressed;
    protected JButton okButton;
    public MyDialog(Frame f) {
        super(f);
        okButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                buttonpressed= APPLY_OPTION;
            }
        } );
    public int getButtonPressed() {
        return buttonpressed;
    }

}
```

then I have my JUnit file:

```
public class testMyDialog {

    @Test
    public void testGetButtonPressed() {
        MyDialog fc= new MyDialog(null);
        fc.okButton.???????? //how do I activate the ActionListener?
        assertEquals(MyDialog.APPLY_OPTION, fc.getButtonPressed());
    }
}
```

This may sound redundant to do in a unit test, but the actual class is a lot more complicated than that...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`AbstractButton.doClick`

Your tests might run faster if you use the form that takes an argument and give it a shorter delay. The call blocks for the delay.

Answer (score 2):

If you have non-trivial code directly in your event handler that needs unit testing, you might want to consider adopting the [MVC pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model-view-controller) and moving the code to the controller. Then you can unit test the code using a mock View, and you never need to programmatically press the button at all.

Comment: The problem is that I'm extending a class (not actually JDialog) that I did not made, the maker of that class didn't use the MVC pattern. Thanks for the info anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You can use reflection to get the button at runtime and fire the event.

```
JButton button = (JButton)PrivateAccessor.get(MyDialog , "okButton");
Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        // What ever you want
    };
});

t.start();

button.doClick();

t.join();
```

Answer (score 0):

I created a getter for the JButton and used the doClick. Example:

```
@Test
@DisplayName("ActionListener test")
void testActionListener(){
    HelpWindow helpWindow = new HelpWindow("menu");

    assertDoesNotThrow(() -> helpWindow.getReturnButton().doClick());
}
```